# Undefined reference to function in C

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to C programming and I have a few questions regarding Makefiles.

I know the general format is:

```
target : prerequisites
<Tab> recipe
```

I have the following Makefile (Please note I have included the line numbers just for reference purposes):

```
insertionSort:    insertionSort.o insertionSortMain.c       # Line 1
        gcc -Wall -ggdb -o insertionSort insertionSortMain.c insertionSort.o

insertionSort.o:    insertionSort.c                         # Line 4
        gcc -Wall -ggdb -c insertionSort.c marksHeader.h

clean:
        rm insertionSort *.o *~ *#
```

Line 1 — The target is 'insertionSort' and the prerequisites are 'insertionSort.o' and 'insertionSortMain.c'. Does this mean that in the event that I edit some code in the target, the prerequisites will also need to be to be edited? As I type this I realise I don't really know what it means. Can someone explain please?

Line 1 and line 4 — Could someone explain in their own words what an object file really is?

Comment: An object file is an intermediate file, containing the machine code and other information corresponding to a single translation unit (source file).  A collection of object files are linked together, along with libraries, to create an executable program.

Comment: This will help: https://docs.cs.byu.edu/wiki/Makefiles

Comment: The rule in line 1 means that if either `insertionSort.o` or `insertionSortMain.c` (you'd more normally specify `insertionSortMain.o` instead of the C file) changes, the program needs to be rebuilt using the rule that follows.  If you edit `insertionSortMain.c`, then the program will be rebuilt.  Make also understands transitive rules, so if you modify `insertionSort.c`, it knows that it needs to build `insertionSort.o` as well, and then rebuild the program.  You don't usually specify a `.h` file on the command line.  If the code depends on `marksHeader.h`, you should list it as a dependency.

Comment: So when I compile my source files I create an intermediate file (the object file) which contains the machine code (instructions on how the machine should behave if this file is executed) and the source code the programmer wrote (which tells the compiler how what to do with the machine code)?

Comment: The object file is created from source code; it contains a translation of the source code from human readable text into machine readable code.  The object file does not contain the source code per se.  With debugging information, it may contain pointers to lines in the source code.  The object file also contains information needed so that the linker can find the functions and variables defined in the source file, and the functions or variables referenced by the source code (e.g. `printf()`).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that was really well explained. On line(1) what is the 'target' about? There is no file extension, just the name 'insertionSort' what is the purpose of the target?

Comment: @user4225083 what is the name of the output file from that recipe?

Comment: @user4225083  the target, insertionSort, is the name of the program that will be created, that is what you can actually invoke from the command line.  You can invoke the make file with no arguments `make` and it will build the default target for you (the first target listed is the default), or you can tell it what you want it to make, for example `make clean`, that tells make to "build" the "clean" target, which isn't really a program, it is a dummy name to cause make to invoke the `rm` command and remove non source files.

Comment: the .o file is not an executable.  It is a collection of information that the linker will use to create an executable file

Comment: this parameter: insertionSortMain.c in line 1 is not really correct.  (though it probably will still compile that file into insertionSortMain.o before using the insertionSortMain.o file as an input to the linker